# asp.net custom control with form field validation issue

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a custom asp .net control some fields have validation controal associated with them.
The problem arised when I declare more than one initialization on a page. When I hit submit on one of the intialized control, form validation occur on all other control that were declared.  Due to this issue I cannot submit a form. Here is the code

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="FinancialAdvisorHelp.ascx.cs" Inherits="FinancialAdvisorHelp" %>

<table width="316" border="0"  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
     <td colspan="2" >
     <asp:RequiredFieldValidator 
              ID="RequiredFieldValidatorMember" runat="server" 
              ErrorMessage="Pleae enter member name. " ControlToValidate="TextBox_Name"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

       <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidatorEmail" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter email. " ControlToValidate="TextBox_email"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidatorDarryEmail" runat="server" 
                     ControlToValidate="TextBox_email" ValidationExpression=".*@.*\..*"
                     ErrorMessage="<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;      
                                       &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;   
                                       &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;      Invalid Email."> </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
     </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
    <td width="165"><p style="font-family:Palatino Linotype; font-size:12px; margin:0; padding:0;">Member Name*</p>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_Name" runat="server"  CausesValidation="True"></asp:TextBox>

        </td>
    <td width="151" align="right"><p style="font-family:Palatino Linotype; font-size:12px; margin:0 0 0 4px; padding:0; text-align:left;">E-Mail Address*</p>
      <asp:TextBox  id="TextBox_email" runat="server"  CausesValidation="True"></asp:TextBox>

      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="right"><p style="font-family:Palatino Linotype; font-size:12px; margin:0; padding-right:50px;"><br />
      Telephone Number</p>
    <asp:TextBox id="TextBox_phone" runat="server"  CausesValidation="True"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><p style="font-family:Palatino Linotype; font-size:12px; margin:0; padding:0;">Ask Darryl your question</p>
      <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_question" runat="server" Rows="7" Columns="48" 
            style="width:310px" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
       </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><p style="font-size:10px; margin:0; padding:0; float:left; width:240px; line-height:12px;">Note: you should receive a response within two (2) business days.<br />
    *Required information.</p>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton_Advisor" runat="server" alt="submit" 
            width="63" height="18" 
            style="border:0; padding:0; margin:10px 0 0 0; float:right;" ImageUrl="./images/investments/submit.gif"
             />
            <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenFieldAdvisorEmail" Value="" runat="server" />
      </td>
      <tr><td colspan="2">
          &nbsp;</td></tr>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the ValidationGroup attribute on all form elements that cause validation including the submit button. When validation is triggered, it will only check other elements with the same ValidationGroup specified.

To make sure it is unique across each instance of your control on the page use your UserControl's ID as the validation group in the code behind.

```
RequiredFieldValidatorEmail.ValidationGroup = this.ClientID;
```

More information can be found here: http://www.dotnet-guide.com/validationgroups.html

Comment: call this control multiple times on single page e.g <AdvisorCntrl:Advisor ID="Advisor_Darryl" runat="server" AdvisorName = "first control" AdvisorEmail="asdfasf" /> <AdvisorCntrl:Advisor ID="Advisor_second" runat="server" AdvisorName = "seconde control" AdvisorEmail="asdfs@asd.org" /> in the page. When I try to submit on control one. The validation is performed on second control also. If all the fields in first instance of control is valid then it should submit, however that is not the case it fail to submit due to validation failure on second controal intance. That shldnt be

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a hard time deciphering your question.

- **Validation Groups**

It sounds like you might want to take advantage of **[validation groups](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2004/10/24/246945.aspx)** . When you have multiple triggers that should validate different controls, this is what to use.

- **Check your Validators and Custom Controls**

If you are still having issues, when validators have errors and you trigger validation, it appears that "nothing happens" (what really is happening is that the validators error out and the page kind of just stops). It can also be possible that your custom controls have issues.

- **Check your Validators and ID's**

> The problem arised when I declare more
>   than one initialization on a page

What do you mean by this? I wonder if you are declaring controls dynamically in your code? This could also be your problem. Each ASP.NET control (including validators, custom controls, ... ) needs it's own unique ID. You can also have more than one validator checking a single control, but a single validator can't validate multiple controls.

Comment: I call this control multiple times on single page 
e.g
<AdvisorCntrl:Advisor ID="Advisor_Darryl" runat="server"  AdvisorName = "first control" AdvisorEmail="asdfasf" /> 

<AdvisorCntrl:Advisor ID="Advisor_second" runat="server"  AdvisorName = "seconde control" AdvisorEmail="asdfs@asd.org" />  in the page.
When I try to submit on control one.  The validation is performed on second control also.
If all the fields in first instance of control is valid then it should submit, however that is not the case it fail to submit due to validation failure on second controal intance. That shldnt be.

Comment: Oh, so to submit the page, the first control MUST be valid, but it is always okay for the second to be invalid? If this so, take the validation controls off of the second, or see if you can add CausesValidation=False to this second custom control.

Comment: I think it sounds more like you have a case where the user must fill the first control, and then if they want to, they can fill out the second, (third, fourth, ..?). Consider an easy redesign where the second (/next) control is invisible until they indicate they want to fill it out. Invisible (that is, Visible="False") standard ASP.NET controls are not validated (not sure for your custom).

Comment: ^ That is: Have the first non-optional control visible. User can click something like "Want to do another?Click here" to display another control (that will be validated) (and probably a "remove this one/undo" for second and onward controls). (Like this? http://drupal.org/files/issues/add_another_item_button.jpg) The page is validated with however many controls are visible, and the user can add/remove them as they want (except the first). That way, you the programmer are not left guessing with more complicated validation logic. Does this help you?